# Prove a subset from 1000 points contains one point that is strictly larger than the other one

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I have been working on the following problem(from Supplementary Exercises of Chapter 1 of A Walk Through Combinatorics 4th edition) for a while.

> Let $K$ denote the 1000 points in the three-dimensional space whose coordinates are all integers in the interval [1, 10]. Let $S$ be a subset of $K$ that has at least **272** points. Prove that $S$ contains two points $u$ and $v$ so that each coordinate of $v$ is strictly larger than the corresponding coordinate of $u$.

I know I should use pigeon hole principle and try to find 271 holes. I also can find a subset(planes: $x=1, y=1, z=1$) which cantians 271 points and meets requirement, but I don't know how to use this special case.
Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot get over the fact that $271=10^{3}-9^{3}$ but i have not solved this one too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's introduce an equivalence relation on $[10]^3$. $(a,b,c),(d,e,f) \in [10]^3$ are equivalent if there exist $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(a,b,c) + \lambda (1,1,1) =(e,d,f)$. Tis a doddle to quickly check RST. A representative for each equivalence class could be to keep subtracting $(1,1,1)$ from a given vector until on of the coordinates is $1$.

You now need to show there are $271$ such equivalence classes (I will show this if requested) and also observe that $2$ elements in the same equivalence class will have the property that all the coordinates of one majorises the other ... and we are dumb.

Comment: When $[n]^3$ is visualised in terms of the lines parallel to $(1,1,1)$, we can now see the importance of Rezha Adrian Tanharja's comment.

Comment: (2,2,3) and (4,4,6) are in the same equivalence class but do not have a representative where one of the coordinates is 1.  There are at most that many equivalence classes?

Comment: @user136920 they don't belong to the same equivalence class. $(2,2,3)$ belongs to $(1,1,2)$ but $(4,4,6)$ belongs to $(1,1,3)$. The first element in each equivalence class must contains at least one 1. Do I make it clear?

Answer (score 1):

For those curious about why the number of equivalence classes is 271 = $10^3$ - $9^3$, consider which elements of $[10]^3$ are NOT representatives of their equivalence class (i.e. their least coordinate is not a 1). It is all the points with all three coordinates of in the range of 2 to 9, of which there are $9^3$.

Comment: Another way to visualize it, counting up all the points that DO have a coordinate of 1, imagine the three squares of $10^2$ points each with coordinates (1,b,c), (a,1,c), and (a,b,1), which are parallel to the yz, xz, and xy planes. Those have 3 x 100 points, but 27 of them are counted twice and one of them, namely (1,1,1), is counted three times. 300 - 27 - 2 = 271.